# Flutter change text when button pressed

Tags: flutter, dart

yo guys i'll try to change text at button when clicked on...

my code :

```
         bool pressGeoON = false;
         bool cmbscritta = false;
           RaisedButton(
                  shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                      side: BorderSide(color: Colors.red)),
                  color: pressGeoON ? Colors.blue: Colors.red,
                  textColor: Colors.white,
                  child:  cmbscritta ? Text("GeoOn"): Text("GeoOFF"),
                  //    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14)

                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() => pressGeoON = !pressGeoON);
                    setState(() => cmbscritta = !cmbscritta);
                  },
                )
```

No advice from dart Analisys but not work...help!

Comment: can you share complete code in which you're calling this RaisedButton ?

Comment: where did you define this variable? **bool pressGeoON = false;
         bool cmbscritta = false;**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this `bool pressGeoON = false;` `bool cmbscritta = false;` should be global variable of your widget and it will start working.

Comment: wowww correct :) can explain how? not write after @ovverride
  Widget build(BuildContext context) { }

Comment: invoking setState() will call build method of your widget and the values of bool pressGeoON = false; bool cmbscritta = false; will get reset. so these variable should be out of your build method. so that their values can be persisted.

Comment: Print log in your build method's first line and press button you will see that when you call setState() the build method will also be called.

Answer (score 14):

your class must be stateful to **change state** of activity

also the variable must be declared globally

```
class MyClass extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyClassState createState() => _MyClassState();
}

class _MyClassState extends State<MyClass> {
  bool pressGeoON = false;
  bool cmbscritta = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
              side: BorderSide(color: Colors.red)),
          color: pressGeoON ? Colors.blue : Colors.red,
          textColor: Colors.white,
          child: cmbscritta ? Text("GeoOn") : Text("GeoOFF"),
          //    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14)
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                pressGeoON = !pressGeoON;
                cmbscritta = !cmbscritta;
              });
            }
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should simplify your `onPressed` as:

```
onPressed: () {
   setState(() {
     pressGeoON = !pressGeoON;
     cmbscritta = !cmbscritta;
  });
}
```

and make sure your widget class is `StatefulWidget` not `StatelessWidget`

Answer (score 0):

**Simple You can make One variable**

```
var name = "safal"
```

**After that make one method**

```
void changeName(){
 setState(() {
 name = "Sahil";
 });
}
```

**Set text in your Text**

```
Text(
 name,
 style: const TextStyle(
  fontSize: 14,
  fontFamily:
  "Roboto Font Family",
  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
  color: grey_color),
)
```