# How to change text in Flutter (Dart)?

Tags: flutter, dart, text, widget

I'm new to Flutter!
I want to change the content of "Text" on click and Button "change Text"
see the following code:

```
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyHomePage()));
}
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          title: Center(
              child: Text("App demo",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.yellow, fontSize: 40))),
        ),
        body:Center(
          child: Column(children: [
            Text("Hello word !", key: Key("textKey")),
            TextButton(child: Text("change Text"), onPressed: (){
              /* **I want to change "Hello word!" to "Text has changed"** */
              debugPrint("Change");
            },),
          ],),
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Please show me how to do it?
[image]
thanks, everyone.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter change text when button pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59334552/flutter-change-text-when-button-pressed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to extend with a stateful widget if you want to change the text. In stateless, it can't rebuild, so you must go with the stateful widget or state management like(bloc, provider, getx etc)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyHomePage()));
}
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String helloWorld = "Hello word !";
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
            title: Center(
                child: Text("App demo",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.yellow, fontSize: 40))),
          ),
          body:Center(
            child: Column(children: [
              Text("$helloWorld", key: Key("textKey")),
              TextButton(child: Text("change Text"), onPressed: (){
                /* **I want to change "Hello word!" to "Text has changed"** */
                debugPrint("Change");
                setState(() {
                  helloWorld = "Change text";

                });
              },),
            ],),
          )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: please mak it as answer, and also try to type english, Happy coding!

Comment: the current way solved my problem, but i want to ask more can we use "Find Widgets" to make this request?

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/testing/widget/finders

Comment: you can write testing using find widgets