# How to change the top header color of macos app in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

I want to change both the text(i.e. readme) and the background color behind it. I am not sure how to do this. This readme is not present inside my dart code, somehow it inherited from the app name. Same for the header as well, it doesn't inherit from the theme.

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69250003/how-to-change-text-in-flutter-dart

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change text in Flutter (Dart)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69250003/how-to-change-text-in-flutter-dart)

Comment: No, this is not a state related issue. This text is not present in my dart code